# Что такое разряд?

Tags: битовые-операции

Что такое разряд и чем он отличается  бита?

Comment: Вот и неосиляторы школьной математики подъехали. Интересно, кто-то в наше время еще всерьез утверждает, что погромирование для илиты, если программировать могут даже чуваки, не осилившие школу?

Comment: вы пробел пропустили , пишется так - `или ты`

Comment: @splash58: нее, это такое специальное саркастичное написание слова «элита».

Comment: Несомненно. Я понял. Просто, я не люблю всякие такие выступления - 'какие мы крутые'...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Разряд](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4) — это структурный элемент представления чисел в позиционных системах счисления.

[Бит](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82) — единица измерения количества информации, равная одному разряду в двоичной системе счисления.